# Google Maps Fusiontable query where clause shows "data may still be loading"

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to filter some data in fusion tables and then show the result graphics.

Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>map</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var sloCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(46.119944, 14.815333);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), { zoom: 8, center: sloCenter });

        var layerLUO = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: 'graphics',
                from: '1bcKOFVL1kfjLOHGTXibbKzGN-4_Xvy_mj73iteY',
                where: "LUO_ID = 51" //if you comment this line it works. LUO_ID is Number type and 51 is a valid data for this column
            },
            options: {
                styleId: 2
            },
            map: map
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can view the table at: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1bcKOFVL1kfjLOHGTXibbKzGN-4_Xvy_mj73iteY

Filter works in the fusiontable GUI.

Can someone explain what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "data may still be loading" in my experience means there is something wrong with the query.

Looks to me like your LUO_ID column has a "special" character at the beginning of the name (If I hover over that ID I see a "box" right before the "L".  That box seems to be a [UTF-8 Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding)).  If I use col0 instead it works (which is the [URL you get if you click on "publish"](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?q=select+col2+from+1bcKOFVL1kfjLOHGTXibbKzGN-4_Xvy_mj73iteY+where+col0+%3D+51&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=45.89086836321722&lng=14.87491614076805&t=1&z=9&l=col2&y=2&tmplt=2&hml=KML)):

[example using "col0"](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoD.html?lat=45.838703&lng=14.969300&zoom=9&type=m&tableid=1bcKOFVL1kfjLOHGTXibbKzGN-4_Xvy_mj73iteY&tablequery=graphics&tablewhere=col0%20%3D%2051)

[example using LUO_ID](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoD.html?lat=45.838703&lng=14.969300&zoom=9&type=m&tableid=1bcKOFVL1kfjLOHGTXibbKzGN-4_Xvy_mj73iteY&tablequery=graphics&tablewhere=%uFEFFLUO_ID%20%3D%2051)

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't find that myself. It works now.

Comment: It looks like a problem in the data that you imported into your table.  Your table doesn't allow downloads so I couldn't test that theory, but the col0 that is used by the "publish" feature did work.