# Error data may still loading in map google maps fusion tables kml querying geometry

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-fusion-tables

Hello Im new to fusion tables and google maps api im in an urge for this project delivered on monday, im trying to query a geometry file but it sends me an error " data may still loading" and I have no response
here is my code grabbed from another website

Thanks in advance.

here is the link to the code
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CfwlKDE3qJ74Iiom-RUtO96GNSyIbrY2YmQ9C0AWrfs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I guess [geocodezip](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1210329/geocodezip) would appreciate it when you remove his analytics-code from the shared document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps Fusiontable query where clause shows "data may still be loading"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690522/google-maps-fusiontable-query-where-clause-shows-data-may-still-be-loading)

Comment: thanks for all and your excellent examples, appreciate!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where-clause in your `query`:

```
 where: "Query = '" + query + "'"
```

....is wrong.

`Query` is expected to be the name of a column, but in the table is no such column.

The name of the column is `Municipio`

```
 where: "Municipio = '" + query + "'"
```